# Calculate height of a webview in advance?

Tags: android, webview

I have several webviews that will be displaying text with html tags. I want to be able to calculate what the height of the webview would be if it wrapped the contents so that I can animate the height to that point myself. Given an html string, how can I calculate the height it will take up in a webview of a given width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PictureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html#onNewPicture%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Picture%29) hook to get the size and run your animation the instant the page is finished loading.  It will happen fast enough that it is like knowing in advance.

Comment: please help me how can we do this ? actually in link provided by schwiz is showing deprecated version of Interface.